# Infix constructor in Scala cannot be resolved?

Tags: scala, constructor, infix-notation

An example from the stairway book:

```
package ky.example

object Example {
  abstract class MyList[+T] {
    def isEmpty: Boolean
    def head: T
    def tail: MyList[T]

    def length: Int = if(isEmpty) 0 else 1 + tail.length
    def drop(n: Int): MyList[T] = {
      if(isEmpty) MyNil
      else tail.drop(n - 1)
    }
    def map[U](func: T => U): MyList[U] = {
      if(isEmpty) MyNil
//      else new ::(func(head), tail.map(func))
      else func(head) :: tail.map(func) // cannot resolve symbol ::
    }
  }

  case object MyNil extends MyList[Nothing] {
    override def isEmpty: Boolean = true

    override def tail: MyList[Nothing] = throw new NoSuchElementException("tail of MyNil")

    override def head: Nothing = throw new NoSuchElementException("head of MyNil")
  }

  final case class ::[T](val head: T, val tail: MyList[T]) extends MyList[T] {
    override def isEmpty: Boolean = false
  }
  object :: {
    def apply[T](h: T, t: MyList[T]) = {
      new ::(h, t)
    }
  }

}
```

The compiler says it cannot resolve the symbol `::`.  If I use the prefix version instead of the infix version (the line is commented out), there is no error.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

The infix notation does not apply to the `apply` method of companion objects. In order to use the infix notation, you have to provide a method definition for `::` in the `MyList` class. The following code does the trick if added to `MyList`:

```scala
def ::[U >: T](h: U): MyList[U] = {
  new ::(h, this)
}
```

The resulting definition of `MyList` would look like:

```
abstract class MyList[+T] {
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def head: T
  def tail: MyList[T]

  def length: Int = if(isEmpty) 0 else 1 + tail.length
  def drop(n: Int): MyList[T] = {
    if(isEmpty) MyNil
    else tail.drop(n - 1)
  }
  def map[U](func: T => U): MyList[U] = {
    if(isEmpty) MyNil
    else func(head) :: tail.map(func)
  }

  def ::[U >: T](h: U): MyList[U] = {
    new ::(h, this)
  }
}

case object MyNil extends MyList[Nothing] {
  override def isEmpty: Boolean = true

  override def tail: MyList[Nothing] = throw new NoSuchElementException("tail of MyNil")

  override def head: Nothing = throw new NoSuchElementException("head of MyNil")
}

final case class ::[T](val head: T, val tail: MyList[T]) extends MyList[T] {
  override def isEmpty: Boolean = false
}
```